# Wordpress Email form not working; Wordpress email capability verified

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a very simple form that is used to create a offer card # base don user input. The same form has a second button to send an email to the address given, but the email is not getting to the destination.

I have tried using php isset (shown in code) and have also tried ajax; neither seem to be working, but odds are I'm doing something wrong.

This form does reside within a wordpress template, and is sending using the wp_mail() function.

PHP / HTML:

```
<?PHP
    $email = $_POST['emailAdd'];
    $subject = "RE: Your FREE Radio Promo Code from <REDACTED>!";
    $message = $_POST['message'];                   

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    sendMail();
    }

    function sendMail(){
         wp_mail($email, $subject, $message);
    }
?>
<div class="invitation-maker-container">
    <form name="invite-maker" action="dashboard_template.php" method="post">
        <h2>Invite Maker</h2>
    <h3>ver. 1.0</h3><br>
    <!--Recipient's State -->
    Recipient's State:<br>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state"><br>
        <!--Recipient's City -->
    Recipient's Zip Code:<br>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"><br>
    <!--Recipient's First Name -->
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
        <!--Recipient's Last Name -->
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br><br>
    <!-- Generate Number Button -->
    <input type="button" value="Create Number!" id="cardButton"><br><br>
        <!-- Credit Card Number -->
    <p id="card-number">Card Number Will Appear Here!</p>
    <div id="card-num-db"></div><br>
    <h2>Email Setup:</h2>
    <!-- 'To' Field -->
    Recipient's Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="emailAdd" id="email"><br>
    <p id="email-message" name="message"></p>
    <!-- Submit Button (NOTE: Should warn sender they are about to send an email before sending!) -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="emailButton"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

The expected result would be an email in my inbox, but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Your form is posting data to `dashboard_template.php`, which is a PHP template file located somewhere inside your theme's folder. WordPress won't find it (the form will attempt to post its data to `FORM_PAGE_URL/dashboard_template.php` which doesn't exist) and so your form will fail to send the data.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for pointing that out! Next question - where should I send it to get the email to go out?

Comment: Well, you could: a) remove the `action` attribute and then your form will post the data to the current page (which seems to be what you're trying to do here); b) send the `POST` request to `admin-post.php` (which is the WordPress way), or; c) have your form handle the data via the AJAX API (which is another way to do things a-la-WordPress). I'll leave the last two as homework for you ;) Give it a shot and if you need help we're all here to lend you a hand (shouldn't you be celebrating New Year though? :P)

Comment: I should be, but this issue is a bit more interesting. I'm gonna give b a shot. Thanks again!

Comment: Still not working. The functions show that they ran when the page refreshes, but no email.

Updated php:

    <?php
        $email = $_POST['emailAdd'];
 $subject = "RE: Your FREE Radio Promo Code from Infotainment Radio!";
 $message = $_POST['message'];
       
 if(isset($_POST['form_submitted'])){
     echo ('running!');
     sendMail();
 }
 function sendMail(){
     mail($email, $subject, $message);
     echo('email out?');
 }
 ?>

Comment: NOTE: I tried mail() instead of wp_mail() in this iteration to see if I got a different result. I also updated the action in the HTML to action="", since I'm not creating a post, but trying to send out an email... unless it uses wp's post function for some reason? I didn't think they were related.

Comment: So, `email out?` is being printed on screen? That means the form is working now. Try `var_dump( wp_mail($email, $subject, $message) );`, if it returns `true` then PHP did send the message and the issue is something else (eg. mail getting caught as spam by the e-mail client/service).

Comment: It's returning false, which seems super odd.

Comment: That means WordPress (PHP) was unable to send the message. Check here for a few ideas to fix that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95016/wordpress-refuses-to-send-mail-your-host-may-have-disabled-the-mail-funct

Comment: I've tried most of those. Every test plugin I have tried works fine. I did realize that the user account I was using the form with didn't have a proper email account, so I included that. No change, though.
I have also verified SELinux isn't running (even though I knew it wasn't a factor, because the test plugins work just fine).

I am getting better feedback, at least. I got an error showing a picture I was trying to attach with html wasn't working, so I cut that code from the .js file.

I have also noticed the email contents show on the page when I hit submit. Not sure what that is about

Comment: Something else of note, when page reloads after submitting it returns a 404 error in the console, but shows the same page.

Comment: Seems you've been busy :P Questions: what "works"? Are plugins able to send mails? Also, there's no JS in your question so I'm not sure what you're talking about. Same thing about the e-mail message being printed on screen, there's nothing in your code doing that (I'm assuming you have changed it quite a bit since then). What about the 404 message? Actually, it'd be nice if you updated your question with all of this new info (including screenshots, if needed) to make debugging easier for everyone.